# I want to put a check that does not delete my drives that is C:\ and D:\ drive on my machine

Tags: c#, file

I have a piece of code that saves my processed file at a location. If there is data at that file that is any subdirectory or files then the directory is first deleted and then processed file is stored there. Now if i give the path as C:\ then all the data in C:\ drive will get deleted. I dont want this. I want to put a check if the location given is the any of the partition that is C:\ or D:\ then it should not get deleted.
Can anybody tell me the syntax?

Comment: Don't run your program as Administrator.

Comment: The programmer doesn't get a choice in that matter. If the user has admin rights, the program's going to run as admin.

Answer (score 5):

```
string partition = "C:\\";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(partition);
if (di.Root.ToString() == partition)
{
   // this is the root directory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first char is a letter and the second char is a colon and the length of the string is 2 or 3, disallow it.

EDIT: Or just check for the colon and the length. One less check.

Comment: The only issue is if you do want this type of functionality on let's say an F drive because it it a thumb drive that you want to use it with and have it erase.

Comment: That's true. I suppose you could create a "safe list", i.e. it's okay to kill the F drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable `file` that holds your file name you could do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

string file = "c:\filename.txt";

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
if (Directory.GetLogicalDrives().Contains(fileInfo.DirectoryName))
{
    // File is in root of drive
}
else
{
    // File is in a sub-folder
}
```

(This was tested for "Intellisense-quality", i.e. it should compile, but it might not run 100% correctly, so please test before you decide to use it.)

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it that way.  You should use c[ode access security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(VS.71).aspx) to restrict your application to have access only to the directories that it should be operating on.  Check out the [FileIOPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionattribute.aspx).   Here's [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302361.aspx) of restricting an application's file rights (it's an ASP.NET example, but concept is similar).

You should also run your application under a user account that does not have high rights NTFS access to file locations that it should not be deleting from.

Comment: That may not be actually possible to enforce if this application is run on a client's machine? The customer may not want the (very appropriate) correct access permissions for their users and so having a "belt an braces" approach to prevention may be a good strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all logical drives and just check if the provided savepath corresponds with one of the root drivepaths

> ```
>         bool okToDelete = true;
>         string savePath = GetSaveLocation();
>
>         string[] fixedDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
>
>         // Loop into the string array
>         foreach (string drive in fixedDrives)
>         {
>             if (savePath.Equals(drive,
>              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
>             {
>                 okToDelete = false;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (okToDelete)
>         {
>             //continue deleting data 
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually worried about the class of disk drive you are writing to (e.g. only write to removable media) then here is an answer to that [How to get the list of removable disk in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124463/how-to-get-the-list-of-removable-disk-in-c)