# How to get device id(mixed numbers) of removable disks in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get device id of removable disks. The device id will be like this for example

> "GD1125THUS58743"

I can get the device name, but cannot get this type of id.

Comment: Where did your researches lead you so far ?

Comment: once i inserted dongle, there will be an unique id for that removable disk. i want to get that device(dongle) id in c#.

Comment: What I meant was that StackOverflow users aren't there to give a fully fonctionnaly code to whoever ask. Users are here to help other developers to get rid of problems they meet. Since you haven't provided any work you've done, I don't think people will help you.

But still I think this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124463/how-to-get-the-list-of-removable-disk-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Yes. above link helps to get device name and other properties by using deviceinfo class. in this type, am not getting device id. but i installed dongel, am getting that device id. i want that id without installing dongle application in my system. Anyhow, Thanks for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

Probably, [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) can help you while as `DeviceInfo` can provide only name, volume etc. You will need to reference System.Management abd then try:

```
var query = "Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where Name='G:'";
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

foreach (var mo in moSearch.Get())
{
    //maybe this is ID you are looking for?
    mo["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: No. Thats PNPDeviceID. but without install, causes error. after installing dongle, the PNPDeviceID generates that what am looking for. my question is that without installing, can we get that? Thanks...

Comment: Are you asking of "how to get the removable device ID without plugging it"?

Comment: No. if i plugging it, the device id is not getting. after plugging it and installed that, the device id is generating. did u got??

Comment: I am sorry but no. What do you need to install to get the device id?

Comment: No. my question is that can read device(unique)id if i insert usb on removable disk?